# Using a SplitString Table Values Function in an Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, `ProcessQueueLog`, that contains a delimited field value that I need to split and join to another table. I have a working statement but it seems rather slow. Can someone advise a better method?

`fn_SplitString` was written inhouse by a long-gone dev. It returns part1 and part2 and is rather typical of any split string function.

```
SELECT pql.*, cl.ShortNote
FROM Automation.ProcessQueueLog pql
    INNER JOIN dbo.CLog         cl
        ON cl.Conversation_ID = CAST((SELECT Part1 FROM dbo.fn_SplitString (pql.QueuedRecordId, '-')) AS INT)
           AND cl.Memo_ID = CAST((SELECT Part2 FROM dbo.fn_SplitString (pql.QueuedRecordId, '-')) AS INT);
```

Comment: Best bet would be to move away from storing hyphen delimited data in your database.  I'm not sure how this can be improved upon.

Comment: if you have hug data, its better to create another field and save records in new field without - (hyphen).

Comment: Assuming your function returns several columns, run it once in a CROSS APPLY and perform the JOIN on the results

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Is `fn_SplitString` a multi-statement table-valued function? Could you share it? Likely it could be improved or just eliminated (not much value to split a fixed number of substrings, like 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach that eliminates the (almost certainly hopelessly inefficient) function, which is overkill anyway if we are only breaking a small, known, and fixed number of elements from a string (split functions, even horribly inefficient ones, are most useful when the number of input elements is unknown):

```
;WITH ql(q,p) AS 
(
  SELECT QueuedRecordId, CHARINDEX('-', QueuedRecordId) -- , other cols
  FROM Automation.ProcessQueueLog
  WHERE QueuedRecordId LIKE '%[0-9]-[0-9]%'
)
SELECT ql.*, cl.ShortNote
FROM ql CROSS APPLY 
(
  VALUES
  (
    TRY_CONVERT(int,LEFT(q,p-1)), 
    TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(q,p+1,32))
  )
) AS q2(l,r)
INNER JOIN dbo.CLog AS cl
ON cl.Conversation_ID = q2.l
AND cl.Memo_ID = q2.r;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c69faf3ad995a94166c389dc78c7e4c)

To guarantee insulation from invalid values missing `-` that escape the filter inside the CTE, you can just change the first line in `q2` (the expression that yields `l`, the "left side") to the slightly uglier:

```
    TRY_CONVERT(int,LEFT(q,COALESCE(NULLIF(p,0),1)-1)),
```

(Though that fix assumes `0` can't represent a valid ID.)

Another possibility if you are on SQL Server 2016 or better (always useful to specify the version you need to support) is to use `OPENJSON` for reliable, ordered, set-based split, then wrap it back using `PIVOT`:

```
;WITH ql AS
(
  SELECT ql.QueuedRecordId, j.[key], j.[value]
  FROM Automation.ProcessQueueLog AS ql CROSS APPLY 
  OPENJSON ('["' + REPLACE(ql.QueuedRecordId,'-','","') + '"]"') AS j
)
SELECT p.QueuedRecordId, cl.ShortNote 
FROM ql PIVOT (MAX([value]) FOR [key] IN ([0],[1])) AS p
INNER JOIN dbo.CLog AS cl
ON cl.Conversation_ID = p.[0]
AND cl.Memo_ID = p.[1];
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=595516d35b55048868592660c803a4d1)

However, if any of the slowness is due to the linked server connection you forgot to mention (how could it not be?), you're probably going to be chasing your tail.

My advice: get the most efficient query (which almost definitely will not involve a multi-statement table-valued function) working with a *local* copy of the `CLog` table (post actual, post-execution plans to [PasteThePlan.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) that you think should be efficient but aren't), then troubleshoot the network connection separately. For all we know, the slowness could be anything from an obvious missing index to a can-and-string network connection.

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely correct. I implemented your solution on the full script and it is 44 seconds execution time. I was not happy with my way of doing it anyway and you guys showed me several different options that are much better, and that helps. I think my slow down is elsewhere and not in the original join I had. I originally was doing a SubString/Left/length type operation to parse it but I found I was getting an error when there was a value that had no delimiter. Thus the travels down the rabbit hole :)

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment

```
SELECT pql.*
     , cl.ShortNote
FROM Automation.ProcessQueueLog pql
CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_SplitString(pql.QueuedRecordId, '-') SS
INNER JOIN dbo.CLog         cl
        ON cl.Conversation_ID = SS.Part1
       AND cl.Memo_ID = SS.Part2;
```

I'm suspect your split function has a LOOP.   If so there are more performant approaches

Comment: Thanks, @John. This was a little less performant than the original. A 705 record set took 31 seconds with the original this example took 57 seconds. EDIT: well to be fair the dbo.clog is actually a linked server connection. I simplified it for this script on SO, so that could be contributing to the slow execution too.

Comment: Hard to imagine.   One call vs two.